# Did GRRM choose Jon's real name for the show?

Tags: game-of-thrones, behind-the-scenes

In "The Dragon and the Wolf" (Game of Thrones, S07E07), Jon Snow's real name is finally revealed to be:

> Aegon Targaryen

Who chose it? Was it the Show-runners? Or GRRM?

Comment: To be honest I doubt this will be revealed yet. George won't say anything unless backed into a corner because he won't want to spoil the books. And whilst D&D don't care about spoiling the books they like to look good and making the audience think they names the character without stating anything makes them look better.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot unsure how your second point makes sense, people thinking they did something makes them look better? Because if they’d have taken the name from source material it would’ve looked worse?

Comment: @Edlothiad Makes them seem as though they have more control over the story, they decide things (even decide things for GRRM) etc.

Comment: In the books there is a separate (currently living) child called Aegon Targaryen, who does not exist in the show. I assume this is the show's writers unifying the characters.

Comment: @OrangeDog He exists in the show, he just hasn't been shown to have "survived".

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot OrangeDog is talking about fAegon I presume.

Comment: @Aegon I know, just clarifying the real Aegon exists in the show but fAegon hasn't made an appearance. I.e. if fAegon is actually Aegon then he exists in both the books and show. If fAegon is fake then Aegon exists in both but fAegon is books only.

Comment: I have a hard time believing Martin would've made this decision himself, given that it's such a substantial deviation from the books (probably; I mean the show is beyond the books now but two Aegons doesn't seem like his style)

Comment: @PlutoThePlanet It is still an adaptation of Martin's work though and so possible he named the character. Especially considering he had a general idea of the story arc before the show started and tested D&D to name Jon's mother before he would let them create the show. If he knew the mother, he likely knew the father and if he knew both of those he probably had an idea for the name.

Comment: The only "Aegon Targaryen" in the main series is "Aegon VI", a Targaryen pretender to the throne who claims to be the son of Rhaegar. Because of this, I don't think GRRM would call Jon Snow "Aegon Targaryen" because it would be too confusing.